# How hot would the Colossal Titan's temperature be?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I was writing a story so I was wondering if there is a statement anywhere on the temperature, exact or estimated, of the heat released by the Colossal Titan? Thank you so much if you answer.

Comment: [Related post](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4778/1458)

Comment: not really related

Answer (score 2):

Found by googling "attack on titan temperature", from [*Kūsō Kagaku Dokuhon (空想科学読本, literally “fantasy science reader”) is a series that addresses, queries and explains the science behind popular Japanese anime and manga*:](http://en.rocketnews24.com/2014/08/06/the-science-of-attack-on-titan-explained-finally-a-titan-tie-in-that-looks-kinda-cool/)

> A 60 metre high Titan would have a body temperature of 602 degrees.

You can [buy the source in Japanese on Amazon.](http://www.amazon.co.jp/exec/obidos/ASIN/4063770400/)

Comment: Is this Celsius or Fahrenheit?

Comment: Could be Kelvin :p

Comment: I highly doubt it

Comment: As you can clearly see in the text, there is no mentioning of that. It's your story, you write it with whatever degrees you want.

Comment: Japan use Celcius degree. Thus it is very likely that it is in Celcius.